# Only port 3000 is accessible remotely in web server

Tags: node.js, centos, pm2

I am trying to host multiple nodejs applications in the same server (in different ports).

i am running 3 applications in port 3000,3001 and 3002.

I am able to run all three of them (successfully!) but the problem is that only when the app is running in the port 3000, it is accessible via the internet (postman) but when the app is running in any other port (3001 or 3001..) though it successfully runs, its not accessible via internet.

I tried to update the csf file and restart the firewall after adding all the ports in TCP_IN = "20,443,465,21,22,587,993,25,53,80,110,143,995,3000,3001,3001" and TCP_OUT

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port: " + PORT)
});

--or--

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port: " + PORT)
});

--or--

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port: " + PORT)
});
```

also, I flushed our all rules in the firewall (iptables), the present iptables looks like:

```
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I expect that I should be able to run any nodejs app in any open port and it should be accessible via the internet.

Comment: You iptables output seems to be incomplete, what does `Chain INPUT` section say? Also since you tag pm2 in your question, you might want to show how you run your application.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you having the port issue. I am suggesting you to do the following might help on this.

1. You can change the port number and try.
2. You can use traceroute to check these ports(3000,**3001**,**3002**) accessing through 
   the particular server. see more info about traceroute here https://serverfault.com/questions/49235/traceroute-tcp-equivalent-for-windows

Comment: I have tried multiple port numbers, but only 3000 seems to allow. I cant find where this is configured in my os settings.

Comment: please gone through proper documentation to add port on your machine. Meanwhile you have a look on this https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AcqibSJ8ng .